# Why sample websocket project in nodejs stuck in "Connecting"? example provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have this sample `websocket` server in `nodejs` [test-websocket-server](https://github.com/avidanyum/test-nodejs-websocket/tree/master)

When I run it it "appears" to have started up.

but when I try using `tyrus` (or any other means) websocket client to connect to it i'm stuck in connecting phase:

> $ java -jar tyrus-client-cli-1.1.jar ws://localhost:8080/mypath
>   Connecting to ws://localhost:8080/mypath...

it just stays like this in "connecting" phase from what I understand it should get "connected".

source of the `app.js` (which also appears in link to github)

```
var wsServer = require('ws').Server;
var ws = new wsServer({
  port: '8080',
  path: 'mypath'
});

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
  console.log("got message: " + data)
  // flags.binary will be set if a binary data is received.
  // flags.masked will be set if the data was masked.
});
```

Comment: Check out [the sample code here](https://github.com/websockets/ws#server-example) and notice the difference between `ws` and `wss`

Comment: @robertklep I looked and updated as following (according to examples and differences between `ws` and `wss`) but I still have the stuck at `connecting` issue, here is an example of how I updated it to: https://gist.github.com/avidanyum/aa46d3612c3c71182269

Comment: Can you try to run tyrus in verbose mode with this line:  java -verbose -jar tyrus-client-cli-1.1.jar ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-3), you need to prefix the path with a `/`:

```
var wss = new wsServer({
  port: 8080,
  path: '/mypath'
});
```